# Macaulay and Modified Durations

Tags: finance

The current price of a bond having annual coupons is $1312$. The derivative of the price function of the bond with respect to the yield to maturity is -$7443.81$ when evaluated at the current annual yield, which is 7%. Calculate the Macaulay duration and the modified duration D(.07,1) of the bond.

This problem comes is # 2 from section 9.2 from the Mathematical Interest Theory Second Edition textbook. The provided answers are Macaulay: 
D(.07, infinity)=6.07079, and Modified: D(.07,1)=5.67364
I have been struggling with Macaulay and Modified Durations, any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: From the explanation given at https://www.investopedia.com/terms/m/macaulayduration.asp, it appears that the Macauly duration is 7443.81/1312, which gives me the value that you say is the modified duration.  Perhaps you can give a more detailed explanation of what you have been doing and where your problem arises?

Comment: You might get better help at https://quant.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Macaulay duration is given by
$$
D(i,\infty)=-\frac{\mathrm d P}{\mathrm d \delta}\cdot\frac{1}{P}=-(1+i)\cdot\frac{\mathrm d P}{\mathrm d i}\cdot\frac{1}{P}=(1+i)\cdot D(i,1)
$$
where $\delta=\ln(1+i)$, $i=\mathrm e^\delta-1$, $\frac{\mathrm d P}{\mathrm d \delta}=\frac{\mathrm d P}{\mathrm d i}\cdot\frac{\mathrm d i}{\mathrm d \delta}=\frac{\mathrm d P}{\mathrm d i}\cdot (1+i)$ and $D(i,1)=-\frac{P'(i)}{P(i)}$ is the modified duration.

Thus
$$
D(7\%,1)=-\left.\frac{\mathrm d P}{\mathrm d i}\right|_{i=7\%}\times \frac{1}{P(7\%)}=-\frac{P'(7\%)}{P(7\%)}=-\frac{-7443.81}{1312}=5.67364
$$
and
$$
D(7\%,\infty)=(1+7\%)\times D(7\%,1)=1.07\times 5.67364=6.07079
$$